# What's the difference between these 2 statements?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

What's the difference between this:

```
if(codons[i] == "UCU" || codons[i] ==  "UCC"|| codons[i] ==  "UCA"|| codons[i] ==  "UCG")
```

and:

```
if(codons[i] == "UCU" || "UCC"|| "UCA"||"UCG")
```

What's the logic behind how each of those statements are interpreted? And is there a way to write an if saying if condition = 1 or 2 or 3 or 4, without repeating the codons[i] == every time?

Comment: The second one is equivalent to `if(codons[i] == "UCU" || true || true || true)` and could be shortened to `if(true)`

Comment: The second one is wrong, as it will always evaluate to a truthy value.

Comment: Just log the statement `"UCU" || "UCC" || "UCA" || "UCG"` to see.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No, the `==` operator has higher precedence (10) compared to the OR operator, which has precedence 5.  `codons[i] == "UCU"` is evaluated first, then that boolean result is OR'd with the other strings.

Comment: They're both interpreted the same way, just with different results.  In each case the expressions between the `||` operators are evaluated.  And in each case the result is `true` if any single expression within the `||` operators is `true`.  In the first case this will depend on the inputs, but in the second case three of the expressions are just hard-coded values which always evaluate to "true" when expressed as a boolean.

Comment: To make it shorter and more readable try 

`["UCU","UCC","UCA","UCG"].indexOf(codons[i]) !=-1`

Answer (score 1):

Visualising what happens can help in terms of understanding precedence:

The second one is evaluated as such:

```
if ((codons[i] == "UCU") || ("UCC")|| ("UCA") || ("UCG"))
```

In any case if `codons[i]` is not equal to `"UCU"`, it will stop to the second condition check `"UCC"`, because any string having a length greater than `0`, is always truthy.

If you want to check on several conditions without having to write `codons[i]` every time, there are several ways of doing that.

---

The first way, good enough with a limited number of values to check: arrays!

```
// somewhere before the loop
var allowedValues = ['UCU', 'UCC', 'UCA', 'UCG'];
// ...
// somewhere within the loop
if (allowedValues.indexOf(codons[i]) != -1) {
    // codons[i] matches one of the values!
}
```

---

Now, only if you plan on using this function with a lot of values - let's say a million, for the sake of clarity. You might want to consider improving performance, because for every iteration of your loop, it will potentially loop a million times  to find a single value.

Of course it would take a lot of space in memory in both cases (with array or with 
this solution)... Anywho, this one is about object literals.

```
// somewhere before your loop
var allowedValues = {
    UCU: null,
    UCC: null,
    UCA: null,
    UCG: null,
    // a lot more values...
};

// somewhere inside your loop
if (allowedValues.hasOwnProperty(codons[i])) {
    // codons[i] exists!
}
```

Note that all the values we care about in the object are only the **keys**, I set the values to `null` but you could have set it to anything else. Ideally the smallest size of value possible, but if you needed it for something else later on in your code, you could totally reuse that structure!

Comment: Thank you, got it now! Is there a way to write an if saying if condition = 1 or 2 or 3 or 4, without repeating the codons[i] == every time?

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly, you should update your question to reflect this need.

Answer (score 1):

In layman terms, unlike humans, the subject must always be repeated with every condition when talking to computers.

To a human, you can say: "Take all the balls from this box where the the color is blue or green or red or yellow"

This is how you say it to a computer:

```
if (color == "blue" || color == "green" || color == "red" || color == "yellow") {
    // Add ball to basket
}
```

And any non-null value (other than false, of course) evaluates to true in a conditional expression.

So:

```
if (color == "blue" || "green" || "red" || "yellow") {

}
```

is the same as

```
if (color == "blue" || true || true || true) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First statement is obvious.

If `codons[i] == "UCU" or codons[i] == "UCC" or ....` then do something.

The second statement  means that if `condition = false then do something`. For example if `codons[i] == "UCU" || "UCC"` means if condons[i] is equal to "UCU" return "UCC". Chaining `||` will return the last value that is after the last false statement.

`5 === 2 || 3 > 10 || 'some text'` will return `some text`

`5 === 2 || 3 > 10 || 'some text' || 'more text'` will also return `some text` because the 'some text' condition is evaluated as true so `more text` will not be shown

if you write `5 === 2 || 3 > 10 || 'some text' && 'more text'` will return `more text`

So it's a chaining of conditions just like the first one  but in this case evaluates if the conditions are false. One after the other. But the problem in your case it that evaluating a string in the form of `'UCU'` will always return true

```js
console.log(5 === 2 || 3 > 10 || 'some text')
console.log(5 === 2 || 3 > 10 || 'some text' || 'more text' )
console.log(5 === 2 || 3 > 10 || 'some text' && 'more text')
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I get it, thank you for answering. It was the concept that I didn't get.

Basically, you read the || that way:

If condition 1 OR(||) condition 2 OR condition 3.

I was reading it like so:

if condition = 1 OR 2 OR 3

Answer (score 0):

So you asked

*Is there a way to write an if saying if condition = 1 or 2 or 3 or 4, without repeating the codons[i] == every time?*

Yes:

```
if (["UCU","UCC","UCA","UCG"].indexOf(codons[i]) !=-1) ...
```